# How to get the Grand Total from row total

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript. I have a table with Product Price, Quantity, Width and Height. I have a single row in the invoice and there is a button for adding new row and delete row. I got the total of each row separately. Now I want to get the Grand Total from Totals of all products. After adding the product grand total, I want to store this invoice in Database. Kindly give me a better solution. Thanks in advance. Regards

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
    table,tr,td,th { border: 1px black solid;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="width"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="height"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="X" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">

</table>
<span>Grand Total<input type="text" name="grandtotal" readonly></span>
</body>

<script>

const table = document.getElementById('product_table');
table.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  const tr = target.closest('tr');
  const [price, quantity, width, height, total] = tr.querySelectorAll('input');

  var size = width.value * height.value;
  var rate = price.value * quantity.value;

  if (size != "") {
    total.value = size * rate;
  }else{
    total.value = rate; 
  }
});

function add_fields() {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML =
    '<td><input type="text" name="price"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="width"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="height"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="total" readonly></td>' +
    '<td><input type="button" value="X" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>';

  table.appendChild(row);
}

function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you to do the calculation on the server rather then on the client. You'll end up with a attack vector just sending fake invoice totals to your database and storing them. Therefore do the calculation server sided to ensure a manipulation-free calculation process.

Comment: I want to do this calculation on client side. This is the requirement of app. Kindly give solution of client side calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is your working code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js</script>
<style>
    table,tr,td,th { border: 1px black solid;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="width"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="height"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total" class="totalPrice" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="X" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">

</table>
<span>Grand Total<input type="text" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal" readonly></span>
</body>

<script>

const table = document.getElementById('product_table');
table.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  const tr = target.closest('tr');
  const [price, quantity, width, height, total] = tr.querySelectorAll('input');

  var size = width.value * height.value;
  var rate = price.value * quantity.value;

  if (size != "") {
    total.value = size * rate;
  }else{
    total.value = rate; 
  }
  totalPrice();
});

function add_fields() {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML =
    '<td><input type="text" name="price"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="width"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="height"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="total"  class="totalPrice" readonly></td>' +
    '<td><input type="button" value="X" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>';

  table.appendChild(row);
}

function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  totalPrice();
}
function totalPrice(){
var sum = 0;
 $(".totalPrice").each(function(){
 sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$("#grandtotal").val(sum);
}

</script>
</html>
```

**Hope it will work for you.**

Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8jo7u4ya/

Comment: Is there any jquery library required?

Comment: after adding the jquery script, the code is working fine. Thanks for help.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: give a solution to add this invoice in database after pressing submit button.

Comment: how you want to save data